# How to know the HTTP methods accepted by a URL using java

Tags: java, http

How can I find out what HTTP methods like (GET or POST) are accepted by a URL so that I can get the HTML content by sending data in URL parameters for GET and sending in body for POST method for a URL like `https://example.com/response` (this is a dummy URL but consider it as a real world scenario with a real URL) by using java code?

Comment: Could you please elaborate or show some code that you are stuck at

Comment: You could check with http options method

Comment: @cks Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

To find out which request methods a server supports, you can issue an OPTIONS request:

```
curl -X OPTIONS http://example.org -i
```

The response then contains an `Allow` header with the allowed methods:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Date: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 11:45:00 GMT
Expires: Thu, 20 Oct 2016 11:45:00 GMT
Server: EOS (lax004/2813)
x-ec-custom-error: 1
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check with HTTP [OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) method.